# how to reuse angularjs data in several view parts?

Tags: angularjs, view, controller

I am using AngularJS to build some sort of dashboard web app:

- In one "overview" page, there are several summary charts of different components, for example: "top 3 persons" and "top 3 companies"
- In a separate "persons" page, I want to show the "top 3 persons" chart again but without the "top 3 companies" chart.
- Similarly, in the "companies" page, I want to show only the top 3 companies" chart

How do I reuse each chart (model, view, functionality) both it its relevant page and in the overview page? What is the correct way to organize the controllers, views, etc?

Comment: make 2 directives: toppersons and topcompanies or i missed smth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **data layer**, I think the best way would be to use a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

You can use a service to **communicate data between different controllers.** All you need to do is use **dependancy injection** to inject your service into appropriate controllers. And in each service have **getters** and **setters** to store and retrieve data.

As for the organiztion, each view should have its own controller.

For the **view layer**, your best bet would be [custom directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Directives are **reusable components** which are available throughout the app and can be **injected anywhere in the HTML.** And each reusable directive can be customised by passing data to it via attributes.

Comment: that might help with the data layer, true, but I want to reuse the entire chart: it has its html bits, css, certain buttons that tweak its appearance, etc...

Comment: Edited the question. You can use directives for reusable yet customisable html components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use services and call the service on your different pages. If your graphs are just html then you can use the value recipe

http://learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/the-value-recipe

If it's more complex you can use something like

http://learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/the-service-recipe

Answer (score 0):

- create directive for chart view
- service for loading or cache date (top people or companies)
  From this point two direction
- inject service into directive and init it throw attribute where put url from where load data
- inject service in too controller and init directive with date for chart throw the directive attribute

reuse directive where you want